# ¿Qué significa el dicho cubano "¿Estás comiendo lo que come el pollo?"?

Tags: expresiones, cuba, modismos

Hay un dicho cubano que dice:

> ¿Estás comiendo lo que come el pollo?

Mi pregunta es: ¿qué es lo que come el pollo? ¿Se refiere a excrementos?

Answer (score 4):

En una búsqueda en www.duckduckgo.com he encontrado tres enlaces que indican su significado:

En http://www.reemberto.com/Dichos_Cubanos.html:
You're wasting your time in foolish things.

En http://www.speakinglatino.com/word/estar-comiendo-de-lo-que-pica-el-pollo/:
To act like a fool. (Cuba Definition)

En http://www.speakinglatino.com/word/comiendo-de-lo-que-pica-el-pollo/:
Phrase used when someone is interested in someone else that has been around the block, in other words someone whom everyone else has already had sex with. (Puerto Rico Definition)

Llama la atención la diferencia en el significado en Cuba y Puerto Rico según esas fuentes.
Las definiciones que se muestran no son citas textuales de los enlaces, ya que han sido ligeramente editadas por @Efren para corregir errores gramaticales presentes en los originales.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el dicho es "Está comiendo lo que pica el pollo" y no "Estás comiendo lo que come el pollo".

Este dicho se usa de dos maneras:

1)"Estás perdiendo tu tiempo": Dado que el pollo come migajas, el que una persona coma migajas cuando puede y necesita comer comida de mayor tamaño, es una pérdida de tiempo.

2)"Estás perdido, no estás atento a la situación": Estás buscando la comida en el suelo que pica el pollo y por ello no pones atención a lo que sucede alrededor de ti.

Y para responderte a lo que pica el pollo: es probablemente migajas, restos de comida o algún alimento de tamaño pequeño.

Answer (score 1):

Puede sonar vulgar pero, en Cuba, cuando te dicen que "estás comiendo lo que pica el pollo", te están llamando "comemierda".

Answer (score 1):

El pollo come mierda. Como se ve que nadie aquí estado en una finca. El pollo es el animal más sucio que comemos.